# How correctly convert WGS84 to Pulkovo 1942 with height?

Tags: proj, pyproj

I have next python code:

```
import pyproj
import sys
import logging
from pyproj import Transformer
from pyproj import CRS

lat = sys.argv[2]
lon = sys.argv[3]
z = sys.argv[4]
transg = Transformer.from_crs(CRS("EPSG:4329"), CRS(sys.argv[1]))
x2, y2, z2 = transg.transform(lat, lon, z)
print(str(x2) + ","+ str(y2) + "," + str(z2))
```

I know what EPSG:4329 is depricated, but with EPSG:4979 i get same result.
When doing this and using these input parameters: `EPSG:28412 67.8 70.3 212.3345`

I get the answer: `7524200.466198465,12554906.059735224,212.3345`

What can I use similar, but so that the height is recounted too?

P.S. EPSG: 28412 I chose based on https://epsg.io/28412

Comment: Do you have the needed transformation grids installed? https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/latest/transformation_grids.html